# Backup and restore Pidgin chat logs

Tags: software-rec, pidgin

Is it possible to backup Pidgin chat logs and then restore it on another machine?

Additionally, are there any services which will upload this to a server and store it online (similar to Gchat)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pidgin is planning to implement [remote logging](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/RemoteLogging) in a feature release of libpurple, though as far as I know there's no definite roadmap.

If you want to backup your Pidgin logfiles, just copy the logfiles from your`~/.purple/logs/` directory to whereever you want to back them up. You could possibly put them into a revision control system like SVN, too.

Answer (score 4):

`C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\.purple` on Windows XP. `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\.purple` on Vista/Win7.